# can't deduce the numeral representation (church encoding) of a lambda expression λx.λy.x(xy)

Tags: lambda-calculus, church-encoding

I have a lambda expression: `λx.λy.x(xy)`, and I'm supposed  to infer the integer representation of it. I've read a lot about Church encodings and Church numerals specifically but I can't find what number is. Can you explain it to me in a way a 3 year old can understand or refer me to a resource better than wikipedia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Church encoding of integers is the following:

- `"0" ≡ (λf.(λx.x))`: Think of `(λf.(λx.x))` as meaning: given a function `f` and an element `x`, the result is `x`: it's like applying the function `f` zero times to `x`.
- `"1" ≡ (λf.(λx.(fx)))`: Think of `(λf.(λx.(fx)))` as meaning: given a function `f` and an element `x`, the result is `(fx)`: which should be thought of as apply `f` to `x` or, in more standard mathematical notation, like *f(x)*.
- `"2"  ≡ (λf.(λx.(f(fx))))`: Think of `(λf.(λx.(f(fx))))` as meaning: given a function `f` and an element `x`, the result is `(f(fx))`: which should be thought of as apply `f` to `x` *twice* or, in more standard mathematical notation, like *f(f(x))*.
- `"3"  ≡ (λf.(λx.(f(f(fx)))))`: Think of `(λf.(λx.(f(f(fx)))))` as meaning: given a function `f` and an element `x`, the result is `(f(f(fx)))`: which should be thought of as apply `f` to `x` *three times* or, in more standard mathematical notation, like *f(f(f(x)))*.

I hope that you see the pattern (and the logic behind). In your case, `(λx.(λy.(x(xy))))` is the Church encoding of the number `2` (using alpha-equivalence, of course).

The [wikiped article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals) is actually quite clear. What is it that you don't understand?